# The correct way to produce random number sequence through pseudorandom naive random number generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, random

I want to evaluate the pseudorandom naive random number generator(prng) in Node.js: `Math.random` and also other third party prng.

The test suite I use is [ENT](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/).

The problem I face is that how to generate the input file for ENT through prng in Node.js:

```
function generateNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
}

const numbers = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000;i++) {
    const r = generateNumber()
    numbers.push(r)
}

let result = ''
numbers.map(function (t) { result += t })
const fs = require('fs')
fs.writeFile('output.txt', result)
```

the file generated from above did not work well with ENT. However, I created another file in Linux command:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=random_output count=8192
```

and this output worked well. I found that the file I created with nodejs is with 0s and 1s as a text file. Maybe the sequence should be converted to a binary file. I want to know how to modify my javascript code?

Comment: Did you create the file with node.js on a windows platform?

Comment: @Psi yes windows 10

Comment: So maybe you need to switch the file into binary mode before writing to it. Otherwise, windows converts all 0x0a into 0x0d 0x0a => `fs.writeFile('output.txt', result, 'wb')`

Comment: If this is a node.js question about creating a particular type of file, then please describe exactly what you want in the file.  It is unclear what the file should contain.  What you are creating with your current node.js is a giant concantenated string of a whole bunch of floating point numbers squished together with no delimiter between them which is probably not useful to anyone.  What do you want the actual file to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ent` expects plain binary data. Here's one way to do it:

```
let words = new Uint16Array(4096);

for (let i = 0; i < 4096; i += 1) {
    words[i] = Math.floor(65536 * Math.random());
} 

let fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('words.bin', new Buffer(words.buffer), 'binary');
```

Comment: Can you explain why you chose `Uint16`?

Comment: A reasonable compromise, getting 16 random bits per call to Math.random(). 32 would probably work as well, but I'm not sure how the RNG is implemented under the hood.

Comment: Well I think that's exactly what the OP was looking to evaluate, so you should mention what effects this choice has (and possibly show how to implement the alternatives). One might be even more radical and use `Float64` to see how that affects the results.